# Pragma for fast floating point arithmetic

Tags: c++, floating-point, pragma

I was looking for a setting that would let me do something similar to /fp:fast switch, but with pragma. Unfortunately, the below doesn't compile
    #pragma float_control( fast, off )

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

That does not work because the documentation clearly states that a value for a `float_control` pragma can be `precise` or `except`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45ec64h6.aspx

Btw, next time please specify what development environment for C++ you are using.